# Using case statement on sum aggregate

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run a case on an aggregate sum but can't seem to get this working...essentially I want to return 1 if the sum of the column is > 0...

```
SELECT Shop.Brands, Shop.Brand, Shop.T3, Shop.ShopName, Shop.Period 
CASE WHEN sum(PLData.Actuals) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Actuals,
CASE when sum(PLData.Budgets) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Budget,
CASE when sum(pldata.ForecastLedger) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Forecast
FROM SunFinance.dbo.Shop Shop LEFT OUTER JOIN SunFinance.dbo.PLData PLData ON Shop.T3 = PLData.Shop
WHERE Shop.BusinessType In ('CORPORATE','RETAIL','WHOLESALE')
AND PLData.Account Like '488%')
GROUP by shop.brand, shop.brands, shop.t3, shop.shopname, Shop.Period
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you left joining, but then using PlData in your WHERE clause??

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? A wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBMS doesn't let you use aggregates in case expressions, you can try to do the aggregation first in an inline view, then do your CASE expressions.

```
WITH RESULTS AS (
SELECT Shop.Brands
     , Shop.Brand
     , Shop.T3
     , Shop.ShopName
     , Shop.Period 
     , sum(PLData.Actuals) as Actuals
     , sum(PLData.Budgets) as Budget,
     , sum(pldata.ForecastLedger) as Forecast
FROM SunFinance.dbo.Shop Shop 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SunFinance.dbo.PLData PLData 
  ON Shop.T3 = PLData.Shop
WHERE Shop.BusinessType In ('CORPORATE','RETAIL','WHOLESALE')
      AND PLData.Account Like '488%'
GROUP by shop.brand, shop.brands, shop.t3, shop.shopname, Shop.Period
)
SELECT brands, brand, t3, shopname, period,
       case when actuals > 0 then 1 else 0 end as actuals, 
       case when budget > 0 then 1 else 0 end as budget, 
       case when forecast > 0 then 1 else 0 end as forecast
  FROM results
```

Comment: Nitpick: That's a common table expression, not an inline view.

Comment: Meh. I've heard oracle folks call them inline views, and Microsoft folks call them CTEs ;-)

Comment: What dbms doesn't allow for `CASE` with aggregates but does allow for ctes?

Comment: @GoatCO No Idea. If the question asker makes his/her problem clearer, the answer can be updated. It could be the asker has a syntax error somewhere... there may be an extra parenthesis in their query.

Comment: Thanks for your help all, it ended up being syntax related to the bad left join!!  My SQL is a bit rusty these days :)

Comment: @NWest Turns out there are no major rdbms that do not support aggregates in `CASE` statements but do support cte's.